# Ienumerable concat not working in for each loop

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to use the `Concat` method of an IEnumerable inside a for each loop, but I can't get it working properly.

```
IEnumerable<Geo> geos = null;
foreach (string a in values)
{
    if (geos == null)
        geos = entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a)));
    else
        geos = geos.Concat(entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a))));
}
```

What it returns is only values for the final "a" in values that too for the count of records present in values.

So if i have 1,2,3 as values, it return only for 3. I need the value for 1,2 and 3 as well.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would check that `entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a)))` is actually returning rows for 1 and 2. Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using, the beahvior of variable captures in a foreach loop changed in 2013

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain it is returning values for both 1 and 2, i am using VS 2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely you are using a older version of C#, in C# 5 (ships with Visual Studio 2013) they changed the behavior of `foreach`. In C# 4 the `a` in `g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a))` would be the last value of the `foreach` when evaluated lazely, in C# 5 and newer it will always be the current value.

To get the C# 5 behavior you just need to declare a extra varaible inside the scope of the foreach loop and use that in the capture.

```
IEnumerable<Geo> geos = null;
foreach (string a in values)
{
    string b = a;
    if (geos == null)
        geos = entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(b)));
    else
        geos = geos.Concat(entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(b))));
}
```

---

If you are curious the thing that changed is in C# 4 and below your original code gets translated in to

```
IEnumerable<Geo> geos = null;
using(IEnumerator<string> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
{
    string a;
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        a = enumerator.Current;

        if (geos == null)
            geos = entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a)));
        else
            geos = geos.Concat(entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a))));
    }
}
```

In C# 5 and newer it gets translated to

```
IEnumerable<Geo> geos = null;
using(IEnumerator<string> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string a = enumerator.Current;

        if (geos == null)
            geos = entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a)));
        else
            geos = geos.Concat(entities.Geos.Where(g => (g.ACode == Convert.ToInt16(a))));
    }
}
```

By doing the `string b = a;` in C# 4 we re-create that behavior of the declaration being inside of the while loop.

Comment: Thanks Scott, adding that line worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott for detailed explanation, this is something new i learnt today.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand what you want to do is have all the `Geos` that the `ACode`. Instead of going over the list of `Geos` for every `a` you can do it this way:

```
var intValues = values.Select(value => Convert.ToInt16(value));
var geos = entities.Geos.Where(g => intValues.Contains(g.ACode));
```